# Laravel 5 Passing Varible from one function to another function

Tags: laravel-5

My coding in controller :

```
            $order= Order::find($id);
        $data = array(
            'name' => $order->customer->name,
            'email' => $order->customer->email,
            'no_tel' => $order->customer->no_tel,
            'date'  => Carbon::now('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'),
        );

        Mail::send('emails.invoice1', $data, function ($message) {
            $message->from('admin@mapdip5b.com', 'Sales');

            $message->to($data['email'], $data['name'])->subject('Your Payment Has Been Accepted');

        });
```

the question is , how to pass the $data inside the Mail::send method?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closures are functions. Functions have their own "scope" so they cannot see variables outside their scope. You can import `$data` into the closures scope though with the keyword `use`. Try:

```
Mail::send('emails.invoice1', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
    $message->from('admin@mapdip5b.com', 'Sales');
    $message->to($data['email'], $data['name'])->subject('Your Payment Has Been Accepted');
});
```